# Nowrap table heading if there is space, but not if this would break layout

Tags: css

I have a table. I want the heading text to not wrap which I can do with white-space nowrap.

However my layout is responsive. At small widths this nowrap will break the layout, making the table wider than its container.

How can I make the table heading not wrap when there is sufficient space, but wrap when not doing so would make the table wider than its container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could just use simple media queries for this:

```
// Mobile only
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    // Wrap
}

// Everything else
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    // No wrap
}
```

Comment: @jdln You are always going to have problems with tables on mobile devices. I'd recommend having a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

Comment: The layout breaks around 900px so this issue isnt limited to mobile devices. As my content is dynamic I need a very robust solution.

Comment: Technically speaking, 900px wide is considered a 'mobile device', you have to remember this also includes tablets, not just phones. Desktop devices generally are 1024px plus. Which goes back to the point I made, you have a very wide table with lots of content, and you are trying to find a way of fitting this in a 900px wide screen. It isn't a practical approach, which is why you have to consider responsive tables.

Comment: I want to keep my 3 column layout when the width is around 900px, and there is enough space for me to do so. Your suggesting I switch to layout thats based on a single column and is designed primarily for much smaller screens (around 320px).